# How do I use IF statement within Execute SQL task to create a temp table?

Tags: ssis

In my Execute SQL task I'm creating temp table with :

CREATE TABLE [tempdb].dbo.##temptable (Header VARCHAR(200), Value VARCHAR(200))

but i need to put if condition like if(temp table is exist drop it and again create new one.)

How can i do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL statement in the Execute SQL Task would be as following:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##temptable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [tempdb].dbo.##temptable

CREATE TABLE [tempdb].dbo.##temptable (Header VARCHAR(200), [Value] VARCHAR(200))
```

**Screenshots:**

**#1:**

[image: 1]

**#2:**

[image: 2]